# Disable zoom only for portrait mode on iPad

Tags: css, ipad

Is it possible to do it only with CSS? 
Somehow combine this with some specific rule

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a CSS way, but you could do it with JS by creating a script that inserts and removes this meta tag when in portrait mode and landscape mode:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

If the whole reason you wish to do this is because the website doesn't scale properly when the orientation changes, then this very same meta tag is useful for that, and can be done without disabling our much loved zoom by using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Though it's not that great, as it disables zoom on some devices anyway.

Comment: Actually, this could work for me. However, it's strange that there is no pure CSS rules for that.